# Possible to Stringize a Pandas Expression?

Tags: pandas, string, eval, display

Is it possible to stringize a Pandas expression? For example, convert `df['Date'].ge('2022')` to a string of `"df['Date'].ge('2022')"`. Sort of the inverse of `query()`. I want to show the specified filter in the title of plots.

Comment: This is probably not directly possible, can you provide some minimal code to explain the context? There are certainly workarounds

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this. You can, however, create a wrapper function (e.g. `my_query(query_expr)` that within calls `df.query(query_expr)`, but you still have the commands used stored in `query_expr` to be used in plots and such.

Comment: I found a possibly suitable workaround. I create SQL query statements and process them with duckdb. I'm liking the ability to create queries as strings, duckdb/parquet performance is shockingly good. My pandas dataframe queries are complex but duckdb SQL always has an equivalent solution.